# How to echo correctly a html line using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to print this using php:

```
<input onfocusout="function("stringarg")" />
```

The ' are not printing properly.

Comment: _Fortunately_ that is not printed properly. Can you please show your code and how actually the string is printed?

Comment: PHP: `echo <input onfocusout="function(' . "'stringarg'" . ')" />` or HTML: `<input onfocusout="function('stringarg')" />`

Comment: 1. Show us *the exact line / code* used to print the malformed HTML, 2. Show us the *actual malformed html* (It's not clear wether it is already included). 3. Show us the behaviour you expect and possibly why (so that we could possibly add smarter solutions)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you can't have this HTML:

```
<input onfocusout="function("stringarg")" />
```

Choose this one:

```
<input onfocusout="function('stringarg')" />
```

or this one:

```
<input onfocusout='function("stringarg")' />
```

Then, to print out in php, you have to use variables and wrapping explicit text by quotes:

```
echo '<input onfocusout="function(\'stringarg\')" />';
```

Note that I have to escape `'` by `\'` inside a single quoted string.

Above code will output:

```
<input onfocusout="function('stringarg')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<input onfocusout="function(\''. $stringarg .'\')" />';
```

use this if you would print the string variable  in a echo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this will give you a clear example.

```
<?php
    echo 'You do not have to echo everything in php in order to display';
    echo 'You can actually breack php code by closing it.';
    echo 'This form below shows the exact example';

    echo '
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="This input is inside php echo" >'; ?>
            <input type="text" placeholder="This input is outside php echo but still works the same"> <?php echo '

        </form>
        ';
?>
```

Hope this helps.